# R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, r.java-file

```
package com.ustr.eMIRnew;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class eMIRnew extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}`
```

This is my code. But it is showing the error `R cannot be resolved`.
I have tried many methods like clean-and-build, closed-and-open the project, changed `import android.R` to `import your.package.name.R` etc. But nothing helped. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Just right click on project then select properties in that android tab just check u have selected android 1.5 or more. if you didnt select android version then select it. i think it will fix ur problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Importing android.R package, which is default one provided by Android. 
If you want to access your own Layout, assets, String. . . then 
Remove the `import android.R statement.`

No need to import your Package.R, By default, R file is generated during built.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the android R file you have to use you package R file if you want to access the main layout for you app. import you_package.R

Answer (score 1):

Remove the import statement:

```
import android.R;
```

In the onCreate method where you set the content view to R.layout.main, your project should be using this file:

```
com.ustr.eMIRnew.R
```

This file is generated when you build your project. Are you using Eclipse for building? Then this should not be a problem.